# update app invalid help

Tags: iphone

hi all trying to update my app on itunes connet i get the following :

The binary you uploaded was invalid. The executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist file, may not contain any of these characters: \ [ ] { } ( ) . + *

please i v searched the web no one encountered this error

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure there are those characters in your project name.